# Is there a way to drag a SUMIF/(S) formula down vertically but pull information horizontally, and vice versa?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Essentially, I am trying to fill information into Sheet A (SA) using =SUMIFS but the information that it is pulling into the actual formula comes from Sheet B (SB) and is organised in horizontal form.

The formula I am trying to use is:

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet B'!AK$1:AK$4350, 'Sheet B'!$A$1:$A$4350,"word", 'Sheet B'!$V$1:$V$4350, "word")
```

Where:
Column AK has the values that I need to pull in
Column A and V contain the identifiable words that I am using for the SUMIF

If I drag this down, the outcome for the cell below should be:

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet B'!AL$1:AL$4350, 'Sheet B'!$A$1:$A$4350,"word", 'Sheet B'!$V$1:$V$4350, "word")
```

I have tried to use the OFFSET function in conjunction with SUM and SUBTOTAL(9, etc.) as well as the INDEX function (though this one will not sum and simply return one of the figures).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*NB: I do not think I will be able to use array formulae in this*

Answer (score 0):

One `INDEX` returns a reference to a cell, two `INDEX`'s return a range.  `ROW()` can be used to return an increasing number as you drag down.

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX('Sheet B'!$1:$1,ROW($A37)):INDEX('Sheet B'!$4350:$4350,ROW($A37)), 'Sheet B'!$A$1:$A$4350,"word", 'Sheet B'!$V$1:$V$4350, "word")
```

Your static sum range is changed to `INDEX('Sheet B'!$1:$1,ROW($A37)):INDEX('Sheet B'!$4350:$4350,ROW($A37))`.

`INDEX('Sheet B'!$1:$1,ROW($A37))` will return column 37 in row 1, this will change to column 38 when you drag down.